# DropDownButton content binding issue

Tags: wpf, binding, toolkit

I'm trying to add MenuItems into a DropDropButton control and control the visibility 
of the buttons using the IsSelected property of TabItem, however the visibility 
of the MenuItems do not change. I applied the same binding on a standard 
button it the visibility works as expected. Does anyone know what is going on here?

Here is a sample of what I'm trying to do:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Button Content="Hi" Visibility="{Binding ElementName=tabItem1, Path=IsSelected, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}"/>
    <toolkitEx:DropDownButton Content="Button 1">
        <toolkitEx:DropDownButton.DropDownContent>
            <StackPanel>
                <MenuItem Header="Visibile for tabItem1" Visibility="{Binding ElementName=tabItem1, Path=IsSelected, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Visibile for tabItem2" Visibility="{Binding ElementName=tabItem2, Path=IsSelected, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </toolkitEx:DropDownButton.DropDownContent>
    </toolkitEx:DropDownButton>
    <TabControl HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="tabControl1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
        <TabItem Header="tabItem1" x:Name="tabItem1">
            <Grid />
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="tabItem2" x:Name="tabItem2">
            <Grid />
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</StackPanel>
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you could get the effect you want with a regular menu I would try that.

Comment: Why should you have to Paparazzi